# NullPointerException Error when calling activity.startActivityForResult (Java)(Android)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

Ok so I am trying to call the startActivityForResult Method, but for some reason the NullPointerException keeps popping up. I got the stack traceback, but cannot figure out where the problem lies.

```
W/System.err( 6973): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 6973):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3505)
W/System.err( 6973):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3466)
W/System.err( 6973):    at plugin.ZXing.integrator.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:88)
W/System.err( 6973):    at plugin.ZXing.integrator.IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.java:31)
W/System.err( 6973):    at plugin.ZXing.ZXingJarActivity.show(ZXingJarActivity.java:24)
W/System.err( 6973):    at plugin.ZXing.LuaLoader$1.run(LuaLoader.java:238)
W/System.err( 6973):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err( 6973):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 6973):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
W/System.err( 6973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
W/System.err( 6973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 6973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 6973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
W/System.err( 6973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
W/System.err( 6973):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also here is my code: (initiateScan(activity, null, null, null); is line 31 and activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); is line 88)

```
public static void initiateScan(Activity activity) {
    if (activity == null){
        Log.d("ZXING PLUGIN", "ACTIVITY IS NULL (1)");
    }
    initiateScan(activity, null, null, null);
}
public static void initiateScan(Activity activity, String scanFormatsString,
                                String characterSet, ZXingLibConfig config) {
    if (activity == null){
        Log.d("ZXING PLUGIN", "ACTIVITY IS NULL (2)");
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, CaptureActivity.class);

    if (intent == null){
        Log.d("ZXING PLUGIN", "INTENT IS NULL (1)");
    }
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.FORMATS, scanFormatsString);
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.CHARACTER_SET, characterSet);
    intent.putExtra(ZXingLibConfig.INTENT_KEY, config);
    try{
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also here is where I call the function

```
public class ZXingJarActivity extends Activity {
private Handler handler = new Handler();

public int show() {
    IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(ZXingJarActivity.this);
   return 0;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            final String result = scanResult.getContents();
            if (result != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("ZXING PLUGIN", result);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        default:
    }
}
}
```

This is how I initialize the Library:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ZXingJarActivity ActivityClass = new ZXingJarActivity();
                ActivityClass.show();
            }
} );
```

Neither variable shows up as null, so I am really confused why its not working. If anyone could help me figure out the error I would be really thankful :)

Comment: indicate line 88 @ `IntentIntegrator`

Comment: How do you call the intent?

Comment: How did you instantiate the `Activity` you pass as an argument?

Comment: Are you sure you instrumented the correct method?  Are you showing us all of it?  Your stack trace seems to indicate that `initiateScan` extends from line 31 to at least line 88, and the code you posted sure doesn't look like 57 lines...

Comment: Instead of sending an `activity` as a parameter, try `getActivity` in method itself

Comment: You should passed in the Context of an Activity instead of the Activity itself. In your case, passed in `this`, and change the first parameter to `initiateScan(Context mContext, ...)`.

Comment: An Activity doesn't have a Context, it *is* a Context.

Comment: I added the line references.

Comment: I still suspect your `Activity` is not properly instantiated and you haven't shown how you instantiate `ZXingJarActivity`. If you have `new ZXingJarActivity()`, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZXingJarActivity ActivityClass = new ZXingJarActivity();
```

You cannot instantiate activities with `new` - they won't be properly set up.

If you just need an activity reference, pass it as an argument. Like the `activity` you're calling `runOnUiThread()` on.

If you need to instantiate new activities, use an `Intent` to launch them.